# chrome extension command-line communication

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is there anyway for me to communicate with my chrome extension from a command-line \ some other process ? I need  my extension if it could get commands from scripts\command-line that would invoke functions on my extension.
I'm looking for something like sockets but since extensions are built in javascript this doesn't seem possible (and the whole socket-like message passing in chrome only allows you to communicate between your own pages or other extensions , not other processes).

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 exposes a JavaScript socket interface called [web sockets](http://www.websocket.org/index.html) which will allow you to communicate from any process with your extension. Chrome supports web sockets.

Comment: I'm not an expert in web sockets but it seems the client connects to a server , while here I need my client (my extension) to become a server(Sort of) and listen to connections.